# Windows Forms Application Exceptions Trapping

Tags: c#, winforms, exception

Is there an elegant way to trap all unhandled exceptions in a Windows Form application? I would like to handle them and write them to a log file. I know ASP.NET has one. I'm using C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To trap uncaught exceptions on UI threads *only*, you can use `Application.ThreadException` event.

To trap uncaught exceptions on all threads in the appdomain, use `AppDomain.Current.UnhandledException`. The latter won't let you swallow the exception, however - you can log it in the handler, but once it returns, the exception will be handed over to Watson, which will display the usual Win32 crash dialog.

Comment: How would I supress it if I use the second way?

Comment: You cannot do that, which is by design. In fact, you shouldn't - Windows application guidelines (which you _need_ to follow if you want "Certified for Vista" sticker for your app, and might want to follow anyway 'cause it's _the_ guide to how well-behaved Windows apps should behave) specifically say that errors should be reported via Watson.

Comment: So I guess I better catch all exception.